# How do I run code on player joining world in MinecraftForge 1.14+?

Tags: minecraft-forge

How do I run code on player joining world in MinecraftForge 1.14+? All of the google results are for older versions such as 1.7.10 and 1.12.2, and they don't seem to contain what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by subscribing the `PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent` (preferred), or `EntityJoinWorldEvent` and check entity is a player (fallback if the former doesn't work for some reason)